# How to select cases within a time period in R

Tags: r

I have a large dataset which looks something like this:
[image]

I want to select the cases which have Status = 1 throughout the period between the start date and end date. Note that each case has a different start date and end date. So for example,

- for User 1, I would only look to see if Status1999-07 to Status1999-12 are all equal to 1
- for User 2, I would only look to see if Status1999-06 to Status2000-02 are all equal to 1

etc.

How would I code this? I am thinking that a for loop may be needed, involving something like `StatusYYYY_MM > StartDate & StatusYYYY_MM < EndDate == 1`, but I don't really know how to proceed. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Refer to the documentation on filter with tidyverse - https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/filter.html.

Try not to loop if it's really not called for.

Answer (score 0):

You have different options here.
You can use the filter function as said by Adam.
You can use the subset function. See ?subset in RStudio
Or when you really want to use a for loop you can try something like this:

```
  for (status in dataset[ ,c(4:14)]) {
          subset(dataset, !any(status == O))
    }
```

With this for loop you check in your status columns for any values containing 0 and you omit these with the subset function.